# Spark Streaming Kafka CreateDirectStream Not Resolving

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, sbt, spark-streaming

Need some help, please.

I am using IntelliJ with SBT to build my apps.

I'm working on an app to read a Kafka topic in Spark Streaming in order to do some ETL work on it. Unfortunately, I can't read from Kafka.

The KafkaUtils.createDirectStream isn't resolving and keeps giving me errors (CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL). I have done my research and it appears I have the correct dependencies.

Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "ASUIStreaming"
version := "0.1"
scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.8"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka-clients" % "0.8.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.4"
```

Any suggestions? I should also mention I don't have admin access on the laptop since this is a work computer, and I am using a portable JDK and IntelliJ installation.  However, my colleagues at work are in the same situation and it works fine for them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the code as well ?

Comment: I also modified libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11" % "2.1.0" to the following (but it's still not working unfortunately):     libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8" % "2.1.0"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the main Spark Streaming code snippet I'm using.
**Note**: I've masked some of the confidential work data such as IP and Topic name etc.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer._
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import scala.util.parsing.json._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._



object ASUISpeedKafka extends App

{
  // Create a new Spark Context
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ASUISpeedKafka").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

  //Identify the Kafka Topic and provide the parameters and Topic details
  val kafkaTopic = "TOPIC1"
    val topicsSet = kafkaTopic.split(",").toSet
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]
  (

    "metadata.broker.list" -> "IP1:PORT, IP2:PORT2",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest"
  )

  val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder]
  (
  ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. After re-creating the project and adding all dependencies again, I found out that in Intellij certain code has to be on the same line other it won't compile.

In this case, putting **val kafkaParams** code on the same line (instead of in a code block) solved the issue!